# Error in getFinancials

Tags: r, quantmod

i'm trying to retrieve AAPL financials and i'm getting the following error

```
> library(quantmod)
> f <- get(getFinancials('APPL'))
Error in thead[x]:thead[x + 1] : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(tmp) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpgrg0Uq\fileafc7f52710a'
```

i've tried to load the entire NQ100 and got the same error message for these stocks as well

```
> symbols
 [1] "ADBE" "APOL" "AAPL" "AMAT" "ADSK" "ADP"  "BBBY" "BMC"  "CA"   "CERN" "CSCO" "COST" "DELL" "DTV"  "DLTR" "ERTS" "ESRX" "FFIV" "FLEX" "GRMN" "GMCR" "HSIC" "ILMN"
[24] "INFY" "INTC" "INTU" "JOYG" "KLAC" "LRCX" "LLTC" "MRVL" "MXIM" "MCHP" "MU"   "MSFT" "NTAP" "NWSA" "NVDA" "ORCL" "PAYX" "QCOM" "RIMM" "ROST" "SNDK" "STX"  "SHLD"
[47] "SPLS" "SBUX" "SYMC" "URBN" "VOD"  "WFM"  "XLNX"
```

all other stocks work fine

this is the text from the file `fileafc7f52710a` specified in the error message

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>(function(){(function(){function d(a){this.t={};this.tick=function(a,c,b){b=void 0!=b?b:(new Date).getTime();this.t[a]=[b,c]};this.tick("start",null,a)}var a=new d;window.jstiming={Timer:d,load:a};if(window.performance&&window.performance.timing){var a=window.performance.timing,c=window.jstiming.load,b=a.navigationStart,a=a.responseStart;0<b&&a>=b&&(c.tick("_wtsrt",void 0,b),c.tick("wtsrt_","_wtsrt",a),c.tick("tbsd_","wtsrt_"))}try{a=null,window.chrome&&window.chrome.csi&&(a=Math.floor(window.chrome.csi().pageT),
c&&0<b&&(c.tick("_tbnd",void 0,window.chrome.csi().startE),c.tick("tbnd_","_tbnd",b))),null==a&&window.gtbExternal&&(a=window.gtbExternal.pageT()),null==a&&window.external&&(a=window.external.pageT,c&&0<b&&(c.tick("_tbnd",void 0,window.external.startE),c.tick("tbnd_","_tbnd",b))),a&&(window.jstiming.pt=a)}catch(e){}})();})();
</script><title>Financial Statements for APPELL PETE CORP - Google Finance</title><meta name="Description" content="Get the detailed quarterly/annual income statement, cashflow statement, and balance sheet for APPELL PETE CORP (PINK:APPL). See revenue, expenses, profit, cash, assets, liabilities, shareholder’s equity and more for the lastest fiscal quarter/year for APPELL PETE CORP (PINK:APPL) on Google Finance."><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/finance/f/finance_us-3578168175.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/finance/_/ss/a/ver=1b0b1eb0rwwhe/am=!xiAxGGlQxoffym1L/bf=/r=O"><link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/finance/favicon.ico"><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-right:8px;padding-top:4px !important;}#gbar{padding-left:8px;height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}</style><script></script><script>
      function _rpt() {}
      function _tck() {}
    </script></head><body><div class=fjfe-bodywrapper><div id=fjfe-real-body class=g-doc><input type="text" name="hist_state" id="hist_state" style="display:none;"><iframe id="hist_frame" name="hist_frame" class=invfr tabindex="-1"></iframe><iframe src="/finance/_/js/a/b/rt=h/ver=t5fUYABu0to.en_US./sv=1/am=!xiAxGGlQxoffym1L/d=0" class=invfr tabindex="-1"></iframe><div id=gbar><nobr><a class=gb1 href="http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ew">Search</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=ei">Images</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=el">Maps</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=e8">Play</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.youtube.com/?tab=e1">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=en">News</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=em">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=eo">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/"><u>More</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a  href="http://www.google.com/support/finance?hl=en" class=gb4>Help</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=finance&passive=1209600&continue=http://www.google.com/finance?fstype%3Dii%26q%3DAPPL&followup=http://www.google.com/finance?fstype%3Dii%26q%3DAPPL" class=gb4>Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div><div id=fjfe-click-wrapper><script>
(function() {
  var l = window.location;
  var q = l.search ? l.search.substr(1) : '';
  var h = l.hash ? l.hash.substr(1) : '';
  var p = '/finance';
  var ss = 'stockscreener';
  var conn = window.history && window.history.pushState ? '/' : '#';
  if (l.pathname == p + '/' + ss) {
    if (h) l.href = p + conn + ss + '?' + q + '&' + h;
  } else if (l.pathname != p && h) {
    l.href = p + l.hash;
  }
  if (h) {
document.getElementById('fjfe-click-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
  }
})();
</script><div id=gf-head class="g-section g-tpl-75-25 g-split"><div class="g-unit g-first"><div class=fjfe-logo><a href="/finance/?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE"><img src="/finance/f/logo_us-115376669.gif" alt="Google Finance"></a></div><div id=gf-search class=fjfe-search><form method="get" action="/finance" autocomplete="off"><input class=fjfe-searchbox-input name=q type=text tabindex=1 value="PINK:APPL"></input><span class=fjfe-searchbox-button-wrapper><span class=fjfe-searchbox-button-wrapper2><input class=fjfe-searchbox-button type=submit tabindex=2 value="Get quotes"></input></span></span><input type=hidden name="ei" value="OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE"></input></form></div></div><div class="g-unit fjfe-promo"><div id="ad2-target" class="id-ad2-target"></div></div></div><div class=elastic><div id=app class="g-section g-tpl-left-11p4em"><div class="g-unit g-first"><div id=gf-nav><div class=fjfe-nav-nav><ul class=fjfe-nav id=navmenu><li class=fjfe-nav-item><a href="/finance?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE"><div>Markets</div></a><li class=fjfe-nav-item><a href="/finance/market_news?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE"><div>News</div></a><li class=fjfe-nav-item><a href="/finance/portfolio?action=view&ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE"><div>Portfolios</div></a></ul></div><div class="fjfe-recentquotes fjfe-recentquotes-noquote"><h4>Recent Quotes <span class="fjfe-recentquotes-duration">(2 hours)</span></h4><div class=fjfe-recentquotes-noquote-notification>You have no recent quotes</div><div class=fjfe-recentquotes-quotes><div class="fjfe-toggle fjfe-toggle-button"><span class=fjfe-chg-toggle>chg</span> | <span class=fjfe-perc-toggle>%</span></div><div class=fjfe-table-div><table class=fjfe-recentquotes-table id=rq width=100%></table></div></div></div></div><script>var _cleardot = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==';
    var google = google || {};
    google.finance = google.finance || {};
    google.finance.gce =false;</script><script src="/finance/f/sfe-opt-2862241303.js"></script><script>
      _regOnLoad = function(f) {
        if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
          f && f();
        } else {
          // Window.attachEvent() for IE8 and below compatability.
          var addEventFunction = window.attachEvent ||
              window.addEventListener || function(ignored, f) { f(); };
          var event = window.attachEvent ? 'onload' : 'load';
          f && addEventFunction(event, f);
        }
      };

      google.finance.renderRecentQuotes = function() {};
    </script></div><div class=g-unit id=gf-viewc><div class=fjfe-content></div></div></div></div></div><div id=gf-foot><div class=fjfe-footer-links>Google Finance Beta available in: <a href="http://www.google.com.hk/finance?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE" class="fjfe-edition-link">Hong Kong</a> - <a href="http://www.google.ca/finance?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE" class="fjfe-edition-link">Canada</a> - <a href="http://www.google.com/finance?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE" class="fjfe-edition-link">U.S.</a> - <a href="http://www.google.com.hk/finance?hl=zh-CN&ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE" class="fjfe-edition-link">China</a> - <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/finance?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE" class="fjfe-edition-link">U.K.</a></div><p class=fjfe-footer-disclaimer>Information is provided "as is" and solely for informational purposes, not for trading purposes or advice, and may be delayed.<br>To see all exchange delays, please <a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en/googlefinance/disclaimer/?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE" class="fjfe-secondary-link fjfe-no-sticky-params"> see disclaimer</a>.</p><div class=fjfe-footer-links>&copy;2013 Google - <a href="http://www.google.com?hl=en&ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE">Google Home</a> - <a href="http://googlefinanceblog.blogspot.com?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE">Blog</a> - <a href="http://support.google.com/finance?hl=en&ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE">Help</a> - <a href="http://support.google.com/finance?ctx=report&hl=en&ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE&exch=PINK&sym=APPL">Report a Problem</a> - <a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE">Privacy Policy</a> - <a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/?ei=OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE">Terms of Service</a></div></div></div></div><script>var googlefinance = {i: ["f.b.id","",,500,"",0,,["f.b.cf","t5fUYABu0to.en_US.",0]
,[]
,0,[["c388b5b8","true",2]
]
,"OudPUfCPNIeowAPQtQE","www.google.com"]
}; GF_domReady = 1;</script></body></html>
```

Comment: It seemss that `getFinancials` function is bit flaky. I got error first time I ran `getFinancials('AAPL')` but error was gone when I ran it again.

Comment: i've tried running it again just now and i get `Warning message:
In readLines(tmp) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:\Users\mbenita\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpgrg0Uq\fileafca934b2f'`. is there an alternative ? maybe a different data source .... ?

Comment: you can ignore that warning.  Not sure if is there any other datasource

Comment: I tried running the source line by line (from the point where `tmp` is assigned, having it point to the file), and it worked just fine.  But when I tried to run `getFinancials('APPL')` got the same error as you